# How the Weapons Attributes works?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

I know there are six attributes (Physical, Beam, Ether, Thermal, Electric, Gravity), but I really don't know how they work on weapons.
There are some arts that causes  Res Down, so I suppose that a weapon/art of that element will do more damage.
But without this, how do I know what kind of weapon attribute will do more damage and on what kind of enemy? There is anything related to the enemy type (Theroid/Insectoid/Piscinoid...)?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

As you fight more enemies you will gather information about them under intel -> enemy index.

Most enemies will resist according to their type.  Here's a few standard weaknesses

```
Theroids: -50% thermal, -25% ether
Piscinoid: -50% electric
Humanoid: -25% beam
Mechanoid: -50% gravity
```

If an enemy is flying, it is also likely weak to gravity.  Tyrants generally have a +5% resist modifier on top of the base resistances for their type.

---

Every weapon has a type.  That type will be used for auto-attacks and for arts which say they do "weapon" damage.